# Polymorphic belongs_to association with dynamic class (taken from other relationship)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've got a Rails app where Users are able to keep track of airing shows and episodes.

To simplify the process of keeping track of (not yet) watched shows, users are able to synchronize their account with other services. They can, in their user settings page, choose which service they want to synchronize with.

To synchronize, I load their profile from the other service, and then run it through an algorithm which detects changes from the last synchronization, and updates the DB accordingly. In order to store the last synchronization status, for each Show ID, I create a "UsersSyncIdStatus" object which stores the show ID, as well as the current status for that show in the synchronized service.

Note that the services do not use the same Show IDs as my website, which means that I have a table which I can use to "convert" from their show IDs to my show IDs. Since the information each service provides is different, they must be stored in different tables.

Right now, this is (a simplified version of) how the DB schema is set up:

```
create_table "service1_ids", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.integer "service_id", null: false
  t.integer "show_id",    null: false
  [...]
end

create_table "service2_ids", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.integer "service_id", null: false
  t.integer "show_id",    null: false
  [...]
end

create_table "users_sync_id_statuses", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.integer  "user_id"
  t.integer  "service_id",                 null: false
  t.integer  "sync_status", default: 0, null: false
  t.datetime "sync_date",               null: false
  [...]
end

create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
  [...]
  t.datetime "synced_at"
  t.boolean  "sync_enabled",               default: false, null: false
  t.integer  "sync_method",                default: 0,     null: false
  [...]
end
```

In particular, `users.sync_method` is an enum which stores the service the user has selected for synchronization:

```
SYNC_METHODS = {
    0 => {
        symbol: :service1,
        name: 'Service1',
        model_name: 'Service1Id',
        show_scope: :service1_ids
    }
    1 => {
        symbol: :service2,
        name: 'Service2',
        model_name: 'Service2Id',
        show_scope: :service2_ids
    }
}
```

This means I can easily know the model name of the IDs of a specific user by just doing `SyncHelper::SYNC_METHODS[current_user.sync_method][:model_name]`.

Now, the question is, how can I have a relationship between "users_sync_id_statuses" and "serviceN_ids"? In order to know which class the "service_id" column corresponds to, I have to 'ask' the user model.

I currently have it implemented as a method:

```
class User
    def sync_method_hash
        SyncHelper::SYNC_METHODS[self.sync_method]
    end

    def sync_method_model
        self.sync_method_hash[:model_name].constantize
    end 
end

class UsersSyncIdStatus
    def service_id_obj
        self.user.sync_method_model.where(service_id: self.service_id).first
    end
end
```

However, `UsersSyncIdStatus.service_id_obj` is a method, not a relationship, which means I cannot do all the fancy stuff a relationship allows. For example, I cannot easily grab the UsersSyncIdStatus for a specific user and show ID:

```
current_user.sync_id_statuses.where(service_id_obj: {show_id: 123}).first
```

I could turn it into a polymorphic relationship, but I really don't want to have to add a text column to contain the class name, when it is a "constant" from the point of view of each user (for a user to switch synchronization service, all UsersSyncIdStatuses for that user are destroyed, so a user never has more than 1 service type in their UsersSyncIdStatuses).

Any ideas? Thank you in advance!

Comment: I'm not really understanding your reasoning for not trying a polymorphic relationship, or even `has_many :through`. It seems like the `sync_method` is the type of thing you'd typically find in a model. Keep in mind that associations like `has_many` are Ruby statements and can be controlled with conditionals. It looks like you're hard coding it into the database, but why?

Comment: A polymorphic association requires adding a text column to the `users_sync_id_statuses` table containing the model name for the relationship. Since a single user might have thousands of `users_sync_id_statuses` rows, and ALL of them will have a relationship with the same model class, adding the column to every single one of them is a huge waste of database space... The problem is that each user might have a different model for that relationship, and I wanted a relationship that automatically queries the user object for the relationship model, instead of relying on it being stored every row.

Comment: i see, to be honest I never ended up using those. But I guess my recommendation boils down to trying to remove the relationship declarations from the database; just keep the foreign keys, and use ActiveRecord associations to build queries. Do you have reservations about this approach?

Comment: Sorry, could you explain a bit more? I'm not sure I understand what you are suggesting.

Comment: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association ActiveRecord associations are the de facto way to query across multiple tables.

Comment: This also strikes me as a potentially premature optimisation, to assume that a user can only synchronise with one service... Even if you only *allow* one service to be synchronised currently, I would be inclined to design the database architecture such that adding 2 or more synchronises doesn't require much of a code change.

Comment: Yes, I know. The problem here is that since to know which table the relationship is with, I have to query the user object. Since the IDs between different services "collide" (and I need to store different information per service, which requires different tables), I do not think I can use an ActiveRecord association.
My question is whether there is a way to do an association (polymorphic or not) whose class_name is obtained from from a lambda/proc (where I could query the user model), instead of from the DB. AFAIK, that is not possible...

Comment: @TomLord Well, the whole way the synchronization is designed, it makes no sense to synchronize from two services. That is one of the most basic assumptions the synchronization algorithm makes. Even then, since there can be thousands of UsersSyncIdStatus per user, if really necessary I would prefer to store the model name as an integer instead of a text field. However, this leads me again to the problem where I have no way to convert that into the actual model name of a polymorphic relationship (even though it should be as simple as going through the SYNC_METHODS hash).

Comment: So if I understand correctly, what this all boils down to is that you could trivially solve the problem by adding a `service_type` column to the `user_sync_id_statuses` table - but you don't want to do that, because it's inefficient. Instead, you'd like to reference a `service_type` on the **`users`** table - and somehow have ActiveRecord correctly interpret how to construct the polymorphic join (UserSyncIdStatus --> Service1 / Service2) based on this?

Comment: Exactly, you managed to very clearly describe what I want to do :)
See the answer I just came up with which monkey-patches this functionality into rails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think vanilla Rails 5 supports what I want to do, someone please correct me if I'm wrong.

Still, after some research into how Rails implements polymorphic relationships, I was able to relatively easily monkey-patch Rails 5 to add this functionality:

`config/initializers/belongs_to_polymorphic_type_send.rb`:

```
# Modified from:  rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/associations/belongs_to_polymorphic_association.rb
module ActiveRecord
    # = Active Record Belongs To Polymorphic Association
    module Associations
        class BelongsToPolymorphicAssociation < BelongsToAssociation #:nodoc:
            def klass
                type = owner.send(reflection.foreign_type)
                type.presence && (type.respond_to?(:constantize) ? type.constantize : type)
            end
        end
    end
end
```

`app/models/users_sync_id_status.rb`:

```
class UsersSyncIdStatus
    belongs_to :service_id_obj, polymorphic: true, foreign_key: :service_id, primary_key: :service_id
    def service_id_obj_type
        self.user.sync_method_model
    end
end
```

With this monkey-patch, belongs_to polymorphic associations do not assume that the type field is a varchar column, but instead call it as a method on the object. This means you can very easily add your own dynamic behavior, without breaking any old behavior (AFAIK, didn't do intensive testing on that).

For my specific use-case, I have the sync_id_obj_type method query the user object for the class that should be used in the polymorphic association.